# how to multiply values from table in c

Tags: c

I am new to programming and have been asked to create a table with 3 variables `x`, `y` and `z`.

To create `x` and `y`, I was asked to use a for loops and have does so. For `z`, I have to multiply the values of `x` and `y` but I'm not entirely sure how to work out `z` and how to place it in a table.

Please help. I have given an example of how my results should be.

[image]

What I've done so far:

```
int x, y, z;

for (x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
    printf(" %d ", x);

for (y = 2; y <= 5; y++)
    printf(" %d ", y);

return 0;
```

Comment: There is a close pattern between `x` and `y`, meaning if you know `x` then you know `y` as well, and from that can easily multiply the two values. That also means you only need *one* loop and *one* call to `printf` in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure should be not complex

```
int matrix[3][5];
for(i=0; i<5;i++){
     matrix[0][i]=i+1;
     matrix[1][i]=i+2;
     matrix[2][i]=matrix[0][i]*matrix[1][i];
 }
```

You can change to char matrix to include your headers

You could see that course

https://www.edx.org/course/c-programming-pointers-and-memory-management

Answer (score 1):

If the task is only to *print* a table, like the one posted, all you need is one loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // print the header of the table
    puts("======================\n  x    y    z = x * y\n----------------------");
    for ( int x = 1;        // initialize 'x' with the first value in the table
          x <= 5;           // the last value shown is 5. 'x < 6' would do the same
          ++x )             // increment the value after each row is printed
    {
        int y = x + 1;      // 'y' goes from 2 to 6
        int z = x * y;      // 'z' is the product of 'x' and 'y'

        // print each row of the table, assigning a width to each column,
        // numbers are right justified
        printf("%3d  %3d      %3d\n", x, y, z);
    }
    puts("======================");
    return 0;
}
```

The output beeing

```
======================
  x    y    z = x * y
----------------------
  1    2        2
  2    3        6
  3    4       12
  4    5       20
  5    6       30
======================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,.....}  <-----for storing values of x  
  int y[] = {2,3,4,5,6,....}   <------for storing values of y
```

Take another array for storing z values.

So now we have `z[i]=x[i]*y[i] where i=0,1,2,........n` also `y[i]=x[i]+1`

Use a `loop` to calculate and print the result.